# Django using 2 data fields from a table to populate the dropdown

Tags: python, django

I m very new to django and python. Have a question on how I can use the model to have an existing dropdown to show not just the ForeignKey field but also part of the primary key so that the duplicate entries that Foreign key has can be identified thru the part of the primary key.

Dont know if this makes any sense but since I m very new please give me an example and I will try to follow it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just render those two field directly in your template's HTML ?
Something like should work:

```
<select>
{% for item in your_items %}
    <option>{{ item.pk }} - {{ item.some_field }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Of course you can't use Form methods such as .as_table() anymore and in such cases you should resort to manually writing your html form tags. More about this at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonas. If I have a customer table where I want to show the customerid and customername where customername is the foreign key I can do this then?

    `<select>
    {% for customers in customer %}
    <option>{{ customer.customername }} - {{customer.customerid[0:4]}}   
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>`

Comment: I think I might be doing this wrong. Can you please let me know what am I suppose to use for item and your_items here? I tried using the class that is defined in the model as the item and model-class within the model as the your_items but it didnt take it.

Comment: If customername is a foreignkey you need to access it's `properties` so it will probably be something like {{ customer.customername.name }}